# parse a .cfg file in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, shell

how can this be parsed? I have a:

**configs.cfg**

```
[django]
SECRET_KEY=!bq0%%mv)u&v6=hm#)^*fpn+cg7(*4xmce=-06@_7ob$aq7my+i
LATEST_RESULTS_KEY=bQeShVmYq3t6w9z8C&FxJDNcRfUjWnZr
URL=http://example:8002
SECRET_TOKEN=ABC123
COMPANY=abc

[rabbitmq]
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=pass
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=abc
RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
celery -A project worker -l info -Q project1 --broker=amqp://${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}:${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}@${RABBITMQ_HOST}:5672/{RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST}-n project1@%h &
celery -A project worker -2 info -Q project --broker=amqp://${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}:${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}@${RABBITMQ_HOST}:5672/{RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST}-n project2@%h
```

Is it possible that when I run `entrypoint.sh` it will get the value of the variables as options on my celery command?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your entrypoint.sh:

```
source <(sed -e 's/=/="/' -e 's/$/"/' -ne '/=/p' config.cfg)
```

The first two sed expressions add double quotes around the values to avoid errors that may appear with special shell characters in both _KEY variables.  The last regular expression filters lines with the equals sign.